# Android JSON или сериализация

Tags: java, android, json

В моём приложении есть база данных, которую заполняет пользователь.
Делаю функцию сохранения на диск и передачи бд.
Как понимаю если делать через JSON, то этот файл может прочитать кто угодно через текстовый редактор. Есть ли способы защиты от этого кроме Сериализации?

Comment: Шифрование. Можете попробовать использовать не локальную базу данных

Answer (score 0):

*Сериализация* — это процесс преобразования объекта в поток байтов для сохранения или передачи в память, базу данных или файл.
Так что сохраниние в JSON - это тоже сериализация. Стандартную сериализицию java так же прочесть может любой. Только сделать это немного сложнее.
Если требуется защита, то реализцйте свою сериализацию и при сохранении шифруйте данные.

Comment: То есть по своему переводить объект в байты и исходя из этого его читать?

Comment: В принципе да. Можете получать JSON, а перед сохранением/передачей зашифровать полученный набор байт (JSON).